# How do I add multiple VBA WorksheetFunctions in the same line?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have long formulas to calculate which launch point is closest to destination.

> Run-Time Error 438
> Object doesn't support this property or method.

```vb
Sub GetClosestLocation(dest_lat, dest_long)
Dim sp As Variant
Dim expr, a, b, c, launch_name, launch_lat, launch_long As Range

'Get Names on Launch Points sheet
a = Sheets("Launch Points").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
expr = "F10" + Trim(Str(a))

Set launch_name = Sheets("Launch Points").Range(expr)

'Get Lattitudes on Launch Points sheet
b = Sheets("Launch Points").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
expr = "B10" + Trim(Str(b))

Set launch_lat = Sheets("Launch Points").Range(expr)

'Get Longitudes on Launch Points sheet
c = Sheets("Launch Points").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
expr = "C10" + Trim(Str(c))

Set launch_long = Sheets("Launch Points").Range(expr)

With Application
    sp = .Lookup(1, 1 / .Frequency(0, .Sin((.Radians(launch_lat - dest_lat)) / 2) ^ 2 + .Sin((.Radians(launch_long - dest_long)) / 2) ^ 2 * .Cos(.Radians(launch_lat)) * .Cos(.Radians(dest_lat))), launch_name)
End With

Range("F17") = sp
    
End Sub
```

The formula works outside of VBA.

I might be using completely the wrong method. What works for me is this formula. I am trying to get it into VBA to then get the information
(Launchpoint name, address, city and province):

```
=LOOKUP(1, 1 / FREQUENCY(0, SIN((RADIANS('Launch Points'!B10:B119 - B14)) / 2) ^ 2 + SIN((RADIANS('Launch Points'!C10:C119 - C14)) / 2) ^ 2 * COS(RADIANS('Launch Points'!B10:B119)) * COS(RADIANS(B14))), 'Launch Points'!F10:F119)
```

Comment: Remove the `.` in front of `Sin` and `Cos`. There is no `WorksheetFunction` equivalent for those - they are under `VBA.Math`.

Comment: `expr = "F10:F" + Trim(Str(a))` and likewise for the other ranges.  Also - you should only need to get the last row once - assuming it should be the same number for Cols  F, B and C.

Comment: `launch_lat - dest_lat` - you can't subtract two arrays like that.

Comment: Don't use `+` for string concatenation, use `&`.

Comment: Hi guys, I might be using completely the wrong method. What works for me is this formula, I am trying to get it into VBA to then get the information (Launchpoint name, address, city and province) : 
=LOOKUP(1, 1 / FREQUENCY(0, SIN((RADIANS('Launch Points'!B10:B119 - B14)) / 2) ^ 2 + SIN((RADIANS('Launch Points'!C10:C119 - C14)) / 2) ^ 2 * COS(RADIANS('Launch Points'!B10:B119)) * COS(RADIANS(B14))), 'Launch Points'!F10:F119)

Comment: You could use `Sheets("Launch Points").Evaluate(yourFormulaString)` after substituting numeric values for B14 and C14 in the formula.

Comment: Just a side note: `Dim expr, a, b, c, launch_name, launch_lat, launch_long As Range` means that only `launch_long` is a Range. All others are Variant (default type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, since I don't have any test data, but something like this should work:

```vb
Function GetClosestLocation(dest_lat, dest_long)
    
    Dim f As String, lr As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    f = "=LOOKUP(1, 1 / FREQUENCY(0, SIN((RADIANS(B10:B119 - <dlat>)) / 2) ^ 2 + " & _
        "SIN((RADIANS(C10:C<lr> - <dlong>)) / 2) ^ 2 * COS(RADIANS(B10:B<lr>)) * " & _
        "COS(RADIANS(<dlat>))), F10:F<lr>)"
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Launch Points")
    
    lr = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    f = Replace(f, "<lr>", lr)
    f = Replace(f, "<dlat>", dest_lat)
    f = Replace(f, "<dlong>", dest_long)
    
    GetClosestLocation = ws.Evaluate(f)
    
End Function
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. Thanks mate!